# Counterexample for Palais-Smale condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I have trouble proving that functional $I:H\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2-\frac{1}{2}(u,f)^2$$ **does not** satisfy Palais-Smale condition if $\|f\|=1$. I managed to prove that when $\|f\|\not =1$ the condition is satisfied, but I cannot find any suitable counterexample for $\|f\|=1$.

I think it will be helpful if I put here the derivative of this functional: $I'(u)=u-(u,f)f$.

Thanks a lot,
K.

Comment: I am assuming that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ inner product?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the associated inner product.

Let $e_1,e_2,...$ be a Hilbert basis and write $u=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ie_i$. Take $f=e_1$ and note that $$I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\sum _{i=2}^\infty a_i^2\ \mbox{and}\ \ I'(u)=\sum _{i=2}^\infty a_ie_i.$$

Take any sequence of the form $u_n=a_{1n}e_1$, where $|a_{1n}|\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Do you mean a sequence $u_n=a_{1_n}e_1$? I'm a little confused with the "i" in the definition of $\{ u_n \}$...

Comment: Also I don't understand how it fails to satisfy P-S condition - if we have $\{I(u_n)\}$ unbounded or $I'(u_n)\not\to 0$, then implication in P-S condition will be true anyways... Maybe I'm missing the point here, so could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, I will fix it. My sequence satisfies P-S condition, however, it does not satisfies the conclusion, i.e., it does not have any subsequence which is convergente.